# Connecting to tor network without installing tor browser bundle, is it possible??? through any Application/Script

Tags: tor

I am planning to develop an application that must use tor network connection. I am connecting with tor bundle and then using the socket(9050/9150/whatever). now i wanna connect tor network directly without tor bundle. is it possible. if so, please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only other option you have to access the tor network is to boot from the tails live CD which in my opinion is the safest way to go anyway, since it runs from the live CD your hard drive and temp folders aren't accessed.